# Enviar datos por medio de AJAX a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Buenas un gusto saludarlos.

Tengo un pequeño conveniente al momento de enviar los datos de una tabla

Los datos los traigo con php (while)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver ya me arroja el resultado de la primera tabla al momento de enviar #2 me sale el mismo resultado.

Codigo ajax:

```js
function realizaProceso(valorCaja1){
        var parametros = {
                "valorCaja1" : valorCaja1,
        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
                url:   'update.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
                type:  'post', //método de envio
                beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success:  function (response) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                        $("#resultado").html(response);
                }
        });
}
```

Parte del codigo en PHP

```html
<td><input type="hidden" id="valor1" value="<?php echo $id ;?>"><?php echo $rownumber; ?></td>


 <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:;" onclick="realizaProceso($('#valor1').val());return false;" value="Enviar"></td>
```

Codigo del archivo update.php

```html
$resultado = $_POST['valorCaja1'];

echo $resultado;
```

---

Actualizado:

Con las sugerencias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```js
        function realizaProceso(idCaja1){
        var parametros = {
                "idCaja1" : idCaja1,
        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
                url:   'update.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
                type:  'post', //método de envio
                beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success:  function (response) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                        $("#resultado").html(response);
                }
        });
}
```

```html
  <td><input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $nom ;?>"><?php echo $rownumber; ?></td>
 
 
 <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:;" onclick="realizaProceso($('#id').val());return false;" value="Enviar"></td>
```

Update.php

```html
$resultado = $_POST['idCaja1'];
echo $resultado;
```

Gracias.

Comment: El `id` del `input` debería ser dinámico y en el botón al llamar debería apuntar a ese `id`.

Comment: Gracias por su pronta respuesta. Estimado Bicho, ya le pase el id (id="<?php echo $id?>" y modifique el llamado del input en id y en el javascript tambien lo apunte a id, cree una nueva variable indipendiente para probar y aun sigue llamando al primer valor.

Comment: Podrías editar en la pregunta, con los ajustes que te propuso Bicho para ver como quedo finalmente?

Comment: Los ID deben ser únicos, pero los estás repitiendo en cada iteración: `<input type="hidden" id="valor1" ...>`. Es por eso que siempre obtienes el mismo: `realizaProceso($('#valor1').val())`.

Comment: Actualizado con las sugerencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En PHP asegúrate de no generar IDs duplicados, en su lugar, usa name

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="valor1" value="<?php echo $id ;?>"><?php echo $rownumber; ?></td>

<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="#" onclick="realizaProceso(); return false;" value="Enviar"></td>
```

En javascript revisa el elemento que lanzó el evento para obtener el campo

```
function realizaProceso(e){
    // e.target es el elemento en que se hizo clic
    // Accede a la fila padre con .closest('tr')
    // Encuentra el elemento con .find()
    valorCaja1 = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('[name="valor1"]').val();
    var parametros = {
            "valorCaja1" : valorCaja1,
    };
    $.ajax({
            data:  parametros, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
            url:   'update.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            type:  'post', //método de envio
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                    $("#resultado").html(response);
            }
    });
}
```

### Opción más sencilla: Envía directamente ID

No necesitas el campo oculto, solo enviar ID como parámetro a la función:

```
<td><?php echo $rownumber; ?></td>
<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="#" onclick="realizaProceso(<?php echo $id ;?>); return false;" value="Enviar"></td>
```

En Javascript solo recibes el parámetro:

```
function realizaProceso(valorCaja1){
    var parametros = {
            "valorCaja1" : valorCaja1,
    };
    $.ajax({
            data:  parametros, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
            url:   'update.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            type:  'post', //método de envio
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                    $("#resultado").html(response);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: El primer ejemplo no me funciono como lo estaba haciendo. Pero intente con el segundo codigo y me funciono de lo lindo gracias de verdad ya actualizo como solucionado.